# How to give device model name (ga:mobileDeviceModel) with Google Analytics Measurement Protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, protocols, measurement

There is no such paramater per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en-US.
In ga.js, it is ga:mobileDeviceModel.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/platform#ga:mobileDeviceModel

Comment: I think the only place is user-agent, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

See api documentation page:
"All dimensions in this group are derived from the HTTP User-Agent string collection by each HTTP tracking request."

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_devicecategory

Answer (score 0):

Android developers have the same need when using the measurement protocol. To do this on Android, simply add the user-agent to the post:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
```